# Get list items with specific content

Tags: applescript

How can I get list item(s) that contains something specific?

For example:

```
set listItems to {"abc","a bc","a(b)c","(bc"}
get every item which contains "a" of listItems
```

desired result: "abc", "a bc", "a(b)c"

or

```
get every item which contains "(" and ")" of listItems
```

desired result: "a(b)c"

I've read the basic tutorial: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-07.html so I'm interested in any kind of workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the list and test for matches:

```
set listItems to {"abc", "a bc", "a(b)c", "(bc"}
set finalItems to {}
repeat with thisItem in listItems
    if (thisItem contains "(") and (thisItem contains ")") then set finalItems to finalItems & thisItem
end repeat
return finalItems
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an oneliner for this in pure applescript. You have to loop the items. Something like this:

```
set listItems to {"abc", "a bc", "a(b)c", "(bc"}

my searchForPatterns(listItems, {"a"})
--result: {"abc", "a bc", "a(b)c"}

my searchForPatterns(listItems, {"(", ")"})
--result: {"a(b)c"}

on searchForPatterns(listItems, searchPatterns)
    set resultList to {}
    repeat with listItem in listItems
        set match to true

        repeat with searchPattern in searchPatterns
            if listItem does not contain searchPattern then ¬
                set match to false
        end repeat

        if match is true then ¬
            copy listItem as text to end of resultList
    end repeat
    return resultList
end searchForPatterns
```